# How to determine a graph is closed or connected

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi I have following questions.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function.

1. Determine if the graph $\{(x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}^m\}$ is closed.
2. Determine if the graph $\{(x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}^m\}$ is connected.

The definition of connectedness that my textbook gives is a set is connected if it is not disconnected. A set is disconnected if it is the union of two non-empty sets, each of this sets are disjoint. I understand that a set is closed if it contains all limit points. In the case of first question above, do I need to determine if the given set contains all of limit points?? But since I am not given with specific function, how can I determine if the set contains limit points or not?? Assume that I need to use the fact that the function is $C^1$, but no idea I to approach. The second question too. Any help??

Comment: This is a general topology question.

Comment: I assumed it. But the question was given in multivariable real analysis class. So I didnt know where to put it.

Comment: I solved it once for real analysis semaniar ;) It isn't hard to prove, that the map $\varphi(x)=(x,f(x))$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: So do you have any hint?? I am really having hard time with this class. For this question, Im only given that the function is vector-valued $C^1$ function and she gave general graph like this and asked to determine if it is connected or closed. How can I determine an ordered pair like this contain the limit points or not?? T.,T

Comment: Use the topological definition of continuity: $f$ is continuous, when the preimage by $f$ of every open set is open. I think, in this case it is very comfortable especially at the second question.